# How to download large amounts of data directly on my PC without using Google Drive? or How to get Google Drive more then 12 Tb?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have an algorithm for creating winter snow composites. I want to process Sentinel-2 data for a large area and download the result.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. You have two questions on your title (which should be a brief statement of the Question's subject), and at least one of them is off-topic for a GIS-centric post.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest would be to download to a cloud storage bucket with `Export.image.toCloudStorage()`. Alternatively, you can try to tile your data and download the tiles directly, as explained [here](https://gorelick.medium.com/fast-er-downloads-a2abd512aa26).